# How to hide keyboard on ViewPager page change?

Tags: android

I have ViewPager, and it shows fragments, one of them contains edittext. When user clicks on edittext and then swipes to another page, keyboard hides half of a screen. How can I hide keyboard, when page is changed? I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
mFragmentsViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(floatingActionButton.getWindowToken(), 0);
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return mFragments.get(0);
                case 1:
                    return mFragments.get(1);
                case 2:
                    return mFragments.get(2);
                default:
                    return mFragments.get(0);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    });
```

**Thanks everyone for answers in advance!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having the adapter take care of the keyboard I recommend you add a OnPageChangeListener type listener to the ViewPager and adding the code on the onPageSelected method:

```
mFragmentsViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

make a general function like this and you can reuse it where-ever required

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
                (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(
                        Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        //inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone, using viewPager2. This worked for me.

```
ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            hideKeyboard();
        
        }
    });
```

//the method hideKeyboad()

```
 private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) requireContext().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm != null) {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(viewPager2.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```